# Listing two people and yourself

Tags: grammaticality

"My brothers, my cousins, and I"
"My brothers, my cousins and I"
Which one is correct?

Comment: You're asking about the [serial comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).

Comment: There should be a comma at the end of each item in a series except the last, including the next-to-last one. Some people, for reasons known only to them, believe that next-to-last comma should not be used. But they can only point to other authorities who proscribe it, and not to any real reason to depart from normal comma usage.

Comment: As a matter of pedantry, when you list "my brothers" as plural and "my cousins" as plural, you are listing at least five people, not "two people and yourself". ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the US the serial comma is more often in general use.  It is also known as the Harvard comma, as that is part of the 'house style' amd so mandatory in all written work.  It is used in the UK too, however, less so generally.  It is often known as the Oxford comma in the UK, again due to it being 'house style'.  Unless a publisher or company have a 'style' that you must adhere to, either are correct as long as you are consistent through a document in its usage and avoid ambiguity in whichever style you choose.  In the above statement there is no ambiguity.